# Android studio Second spinner stuck at the first choice selected

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have two spinner where the second spinner is connected to the first one. The second spinner drop down but always stuck at the first choice and shows the Toast constantly.

How do I fix the second spinner onItemSelected and the Toast?

Thank you

```
content_main.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select program:" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/program_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/program_arrays" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select course:" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/course_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

--

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner program_spinner, course_spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    program_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.program_spinner);
    course_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.course_spinner);

    program_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    course_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                           long arg3) {
    String program = String.valueOf(program_spinner.getSelectedItem());
    String course = String.valueOf(course_spinner.getSelectedItem());
    switch(program) {
        case "Accounting":
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.accounting_course_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            course_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            break;
        case "Nursing":
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.nursing_course_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            course_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), program, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), course, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and `dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();` and run. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your above code with below and try to learn properly the basics first:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
   Spinner program_spinner, course_spinner;
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter=null;
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter2=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

program_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.program_spinner);
course_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.course_spinner);

dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.accounting_course_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

dataAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.nursing_course_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);



program_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
course_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                       long arg3) {
switch(arg1.getId()) {
    case R.id.program_spinner:
         String program = String.valueOf(program_spinner.getSelectedItem());

    switch(program) {
    case "Accounting":
        course_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        break;
    case "Nursing":
        course_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        break;
        }
         //do whatever when selecting item from your first spinner
        break;
    case R.id.course_spinner:
        //do whatever when selecting item from your secondspinner
        break;
}

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}

}
```

Comment: "try to learn properly the basics first" .. So what basics is there in your answer??

Comment: @Drv By the second spinner connected to the first spinner I meant the course_spinner are depends on program_spinner. So if the user select "Nursing" in program_spinner, the course_spinner are going to show list of nursing course.
Your solution separated the spinners and set the course_spinner list to show nursing_course_arrays no matter what.

Comment: @whistle Am Sorry I 've edited my code and I misunderstood your question. Sorry my mistake.